Правило триггера для указания пути к папке репозитория в TeamCity
Есть .NET приложение. Прошу помощи в теме настройки правил для триггера, чтобы билд конфигурации собирались при обнаружении изменения в определенных папках. Репозиторий 1, но в нем разные WebAPI есть. Вот хочу завести правило на конкретный путь в репозитории для отслеживания изменений триггером TeamCity. Перепробовал все, что знал в этой теме.
Сейчас мои настройки триггера VCS выглядят так.
+:LeokaEstetica.Platform.ProjectManagement/*
Пробовал и так +:LeokaEstetica.Platform.ProjectManagement/**
Пробовал и так.
+:LeokaEstetica.Platform.ProjectManagement*
Т.е. я хочу, что сборка запускалась при обнаружении изменений в этой папки.
Предоставляю path from context root
LeokaEstetica.Platform.ProjectManagement/LeokaEstetica.Platform.ProjectManagement.csproj
Предоставляю path from repository root
LeokaEstetica.Platform.ProjectManagement/LeokaEstetica.Platform.ProjectManagement.csproj
Внутри лежат другие папки и тд. Все это триггер должен учитывать, чтоб запустить сборку при изменениях там.
Заранее благодарю всех, кто попытается помочь и подсказать!
